# Get Outlook.exe to open a message given a message ID

Tags: outlook, office365

I have the message ID of an email in OWA. I would like to open the email using outlook.exe by passing the message ID.

For example Exchange online provides the following link like below.
https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/readconv/AAQkADJmNmE0ZjAwLTFlYS04ZWYwLWIyOTgyMTYyODk2ZgAQAK%2BgStiM%3D?popoutv2=1&version=20210524004.16

Is it possible to open this email in the outlook desktop client with just the message ID
AAQkADJmNmE0ZjAwLTFlYS04ZWYwLWIyOTgyMTYyODk2ZgAQAK%2BgStiM%3D

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the EWS id to entry id using [ConvertId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/convertid-operation) EWS operation, you can then use the entry id to call `Namespace.GetItemFromID` in OOM.